# Confused about how to work with local rings for an arbitrary variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, local-rings

Time for my latest dumb algebraic geometry question as I try to self learn through Hartshorne. I am currently trying to do the exercises in chapter 1 without looking at solutions. One method I have used several times now seems suspect to me and I wanted to run through the general process. Say I have an arbitrary variety $X$. In our case it is general enough to say it's quasi-projective. I want to consider the local ring at a point $P \in X$, say $\mathcal{O}_{P}$, defined as being equivalence classes of pairs $\left <\phi_{U}, U \right>$ in the usual way.

Is it valid for me to take an affine neighbourhood $V$ of $P$ and so all equivalence classes in $\mathcal{O}_{P}$ will have a representation of the form $\left< \phi _{U \cap V}, U \cap V \right>$ and so now my local ring is determined completely by the affine neighbourhood, and so it simply the coordinate ring of $V$ localized at $\mathfrak{m}_{P}$. Is this a valid argument? I am skeptical since then it would seem that every local ring on any arbitrary variety is nothing more than the localization of an affine algebra at a maximal ideal. But I thought this would only work for affine varieties, since that is where you get the nice correspondence with affine algebras. It just seems that if what I have done is correct then local rings don't seem to carry much information, if that makes sense?

I apologize if this is a poorly framed or vague question, it's just that my intuition seems to be doubting me.

Any feedback would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: This is completely valid. You are choosing a cofinal subset of the limit, and by basic category theory, this converges to the same limit. The point of schemes is that the local rings are simple, but they vary to give important information.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. Much appreciated. One further question on commutative algebra though. Suppose we have two coordinate rings $A(U)$ and $A(V)$ which are isomorphic when localized at $\mathfrak{m}_{P}$ and $\mathfrak{m}_{Q}$ so that $$ A(U)_{\mathfrak{m}_{P}} \simeq A(V)_{\mathfrak{m}_{Q}} $$

I want to find an isomorphism between $U$ and $V$ that sends $P$ to $Q$. How do I infer this from the isomorphism of local rings? Surely I would need the coordinate rings themselves to be isomorphic?

Comment: Ok, so I have made some progress. I have established that clearly the field of fractions of each of these local rings is the same, so we have $$K(U) \simeq K(V). $$ This in turn shows that $U$ and $V$ are birationally equivalent and hence they have isomorphic open subsets. I am still unsure why that isomorphism must necessarily send $P$ to $Q$ though.

Comment: Take $U=Spec(k[x, y]/(xy))$ and $V=Spec(k[x])$ and localize at $m_P=m_Q=(x-1, y)$. These rings become isomorphic, despite not being isomorphic in the nonlocalized version. In general, your second comment is all that can be established, that $U$ and $V$ are locally isomorphic, but nothing else.